# Down-sets in posets and directed sets

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

Let P be a poset and let us say that a subset A of P is a down-set if:
$$x \in A, y < x \implies y \in A.$$

A directed set is a poset P such that for every two elements, $a,b \in P$ we can find $c \in P$ such that $c \geq a $ and $c \geq b$. Now, I am trying to prove the following statement:

**A poset P is directed if and only if for every finite down-set D we can find a $c \in P$ such that $c \geq d, \forall d \in D$.**

One direction is very easy, namely, to show that if a poset is directed, we can find such an upper bound for every finite down-set. The other direction seems a bit more tricky, but I suspect there's something obvious I am missing here. How could I show the other implication?

**Is the statement really true?** What about say $\mathbb{Z} \amalg \mathbb{Z}$, with the usual order on each factor? Are there any non-empty finite down-sets here? For what I can see, $\mathbb{Z} \amalg \mathbb{Z}$ is not directed, yet if there are no other finite down-sets than the empty set, then it satisfies the statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is correct and shows that the statement you're trying to prove is wrong. There's not much else to say!